Imaginary quantities in the solution of ODE - What do they mean?
In a system of ODEs,
$$y_1' = 4y_2 + 5e^t$$
$$y_2' = -y_1 -20e^{-t} $$
with initial conditions such as $y_1(0) =1$ and $y_2(0) = 0$, if you get a solution of the ODEs as $$y_1  = -6\cos2t -i40\sin2t + 5e^t $$ and $$y_2 = -20\cos2t +3\sin2t + 20e^{-t},$$  What does the term $i40\sin2t$ in the solution of $y_1$ mean?
The method used is this:
The system of ODEs are of the form
$$y' = Ay + g ------ (equation 1) $$ where
$$ y = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}$$ and
$$ y' = \begin{pmatrix} y_1' \\ y_2' \end{pmatrix}$$
The matrix A =$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 4 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and g = $\begin{pmatrix} 5e^t \\ -20e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$
After solving the characteristic equation, the following solution was obtained for the homogeneous ODE with the eigen vectors
$\begin{pmatrix} -2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
Solution of homogeneous equation is
$$y_{h} = c_{1} \begin{pmatrix} -2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}e^{2it}  + c_{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}e^{-2it} $$
For the particular solution, the following substitution for a solution was used:
$y_{p1} = k_1e^t $
$y_{p2} = k_{2}e^{-t}$
By substituting $y_{p1}$ and $y_{p2}$ in (1) and comparing coefficients of $e^{t}$ and $e^{-t}$, $k_1 = 5$, $k_2 = 20$.
Expanding $y_h$,
$$y_h =  \begin{pmatrix} -2ic_1e^{2it} +2ic_2e^{-2it} \\ c_1e^{2it} + c_2e^{-2it} \end{pmatrix} $$
Using euler's theorem,  $e^{2it} = cos2t + isin2t$,  $e^{-2it} = cos2t - isin2t$, expanding $y_h$ further and substituting $y_h$ and $y_p$ in $y = y_h + y_p$ and using initial conditions  $y_1(0) =1$ and $y_2(0) = 0$,  the following equation was obtained
$y = \begin{pmatrix} 2i(c_1 - c_2)cos2t -2(c_1 -c_2)sin2t \\ (c_1 + c_2)cos2t + i(c1-c2)sin2t \end{pmatrix}e^{-2it} $ + \begin{pmatrix} 5e^t \\ 20e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}
Substituting $i(c_1 - c_2) = A$, $ (c_1 - c_2) = B$ and $(c_1 + c_2) = C$ and substituting initial conditions,
$1 = 2A +5$, $0 = C + 20$,  A= 3, C = -20, $B = \frac{-20}{i}$.
With these, $y_1$ and $y_2 $ are obtained as:
$$y_1  = -6\cos2t -i40\sin2t + 5e^t $$ $$y_2 = -20\cos2t +3\sin2t + 20e^{-t},$$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Evaluating your $y_1$ solution at $t=0$ yields $y_1(0)=-1$, so is not a valid solution to the differential equation. (The solutions also don't satisfy the differential equations themselves.)

It means you made an error in your calculations. Real ODE with real IC only ever have completely real solutions. One would need to know what solution method you used to tell more.

To be valid particular solutions, they should satisfy the entire inhomogeneous differential equation: $y_{1p}'=4y_{2p}+5e^t, y_{2p}'=-y_{1p}-20e^{-t}$. But your chosen solutions instead satisfy $y_{1p}'=5e^t$, $y_{2p}'=-20e^{-t}$. (I would also suggest that, while your homogeneous solutions are valid, they're not the best choice for real ICs. Instead it's better to combine them to get a pair of solutions which are explicitly real.)

For particular solution, I used $y_p' = Ay_p + g$.  and thereafter I compared coefficients to obtain $k_1$ and $k_2$.

That may have been your intention, but your chosen solutions do not (and cannot) fulfill what you've indicated. (I say cannot because $A$ acting on $(k_1 e^t,k_2 e^{-t})$ will mix $e^{\pm t}$ between the two components.)

in $y_p'=Ay_p+g.$, I compared coefficients of $e^{t}$ and $e^{-t}$ and with that I got $k_1 = 5$, $k_2 = 20$.

It appears if the problem had more initial conditions which null cosine terms, then B above, would not have been imaginary

If the other solution of Homogeneous ODE was used which is $y_h = \begin{pmatrix} Acos2t + Bsin2t \ Ccos2t +D sin2t \end{pmatrix} $, then its difficult to find values of B and D. to form a real solution of the homogeneous ODE

Lutz Lehmann, The solution has imaginary numbers which were converted to real numbers by using algebraic manipulation like $c_1 +ic_2 = c_1'$ and $i(c_1-c_2) = c_2'$ . Here, $c_1'$ and $c_2'$ are perceived as real but they have imaginary components.

I will follow Example 3 and agree with your homogeneous solution
$$y_{h} = c_{1} \begin{pmatrix} -2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}e^{2it}  + c_{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}e^{-2it}$$
We will use Euler's Formula* to expand the first item as
$$e^{2it}\begin{pmatrix} -2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = (\cos 2t + i \sin 2t) \begin{pmatrix} -2i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \sin 2t \\ \cos 2t \end{pmatrix} + i \begin{pmatrix} -2 \cos 2t \\ \sin 2t \end{pmatrix}$$
From this, we can write the solution
$$Y_h(t) = c_1  \begin{pmatrix} 2 \sin 2t \\ \cos 2t \end{pmatrix} + c_2 \begin{pmatrix} -2 \cos 2t \\ \sin 2t \end{pmatrix}$$
Can you continue from here?
Update
Using the above, we arrive at
$$\begin{align} y_1(t) &= -16 e^{-t}+e^t-6 \sin 2 t+16 \cos 2 t \\ y_2(t) &= 4 e^{-t}-e^t-8 \sin 2 t-3 \cos 2 t \end{align}$$
You can use these and verify that it satisfies the left-hand and right-hand sides of the system.
Another solution is
$$\begin{align} y_1(t) &= e^t+2 \sin 2 t \\ y_2(t) &= - e^t  + \cos 2 t \end{align}$$
You can also verify that this solution satisfies the system.
Update 2
We can easily verify the first solution is correct.
Taking the derivative of the first equation and substituting in the second, we have
$$y_1''(t) = 4(-y_1(t) - 20 e^{-t}) + 5 e^t, y_1(0) = 1, y_1'(0) = 5$$
Solving this
$$y_1(t) = -16 e^{-t}+e^t-6 \sin 2 t+16 \cos 2 t$$
This can then be used in the second equation to find $y_2(t)$ and you get the same as the first solution above.
Compare that solution to the first one above and they match exactly.

Thanks, I got the solution for $y_h$ as in real terms with $c_1 = -20$ and $c_2 = 3$ in your last equation.

I would wait until I have a $y_p$ before finding those constants, for example, see https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx

Interestingly, the method for obtaining $y_p$ above doesn't give correct result for these ODEs even though valid for other ODEs.

@AmitM: Please see the two updates above. What is shown in the original solution is correct and I verify that using two different methods.

How did you derive $y_p$? What was your method?

I will try with the substitution for solution:  $y_{p1} = ae^t + be^{-t} $ and   $y_{p2} = ce^t + de^{-t} $  and see if that would result your solution.

I used Example 3 in the link for the first solution from the $y_h$ I show. It is a bit cumbersome with all the trig functions but doable.

I seem to have got the same $y_p$ as you by trying the substitution for solution above. With $y_p$ available, coefficients in $y_h$ are easily obtainable.
